# Heroku Scheduler.rake set up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rake

Following the [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/127-rake-in-background?autoplay=true) am trying to set up a scheduled rake task to send an email to an administrator user:

```
desc 'Testing rake task to generate email'
task :overtime_report => :environment do

  hospital_bookings = HospitalBooking.scoped
  hospital_booking = hospital_bookings
  user = User.where(:roles => :administrator)


  if params[:format] == 'pdf'
    hospital_bookings = hospital_bookings.where(:day => Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month)
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      render :pdf => "#{Date.today.strftime('%B')} Overtime Report",
             :header => {:html => {:template => 'layouts/pdf.html.erb'}}
      OvertimeMailer.overtime_pdf(user, hospital_booking).deliver
    end
  end
end
```

**Controller**

```
class HospitalBookingsController < ApplicationController

  #load_and_authorize_resource
  before_filter :admin_user, :only => [:index]

  def index
    @hospital_bookings = HospitalBooking.scoped
    system "rake overtime_report Mail_ID=#{params[:id]} &"
    flash[:notice] = 'Delivering Overtime Report'
  end
```

Just need a bit of guidance if I am heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much of your code makes sense I'm afraid:

- A rake task is not an action in a controller so your use of `params` and `respond_to` will not work at all.
- If it's a scheduled task to be run at a certain interval then you don't want a controller at all.
- Your controller contains a huge security vulnerability by passing user input directly to the command line in the form of `Mail_ID=#{params[:id]}`.
- Passing the Mail_ID option above into the rake task doesn't make sense as it's never used.
- You should never call system commands from a controller.
- `hospital_booking = hospital_bookings` makes no sense as it does nothing.
- `render` isn't going to do anything either, that's the responsibility of the ActionMailer object you create.

You probably want something like:

```
desc 'Send hospital bookings overtime report'
task :overtime_report => :environment do
  bookings = HospitalBooking.where(:day => Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month).all
  user = User.where(:roles => :administrator).first
  OvertimeMailer.overtime_pdf(user, hospital_bookings).deliver
end
```